# React, Redux and webAPI, how these three things hook up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Please clarify my understand is correct:

1. React using the state/props to show the UI.
2. Redux is the application store.
3. webAPI provide an interface for update / receive backend information.

My problem is how these three components work together, let's solve the communication between redux and webAPI, it can be solved by using `middleware`. So, I can use different reducer in react to update state on the application.

It is an active update situation:

1. User interactive with the UI.
2. Once the react's state update, a reducer will update the redux's state.
3. The reducer update the webAPI about the client update's the data.

But I don't understand a passive update situation:

1. User did not interactive with UI.
2. Somehow the database is updated.
3. The UI need to update.

So, what I can do is have something to keep checking the server's least status? If there is an update, I need to call the reducer to update the client's information?
Any advise?